# How to pass parameters of rs Utility to Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameter-passing

I have a Powershell Script, say `TestReports.ps1`. In this file I have parameters like

1. SourceReportFolderName
2. TargetReportFolderName where the Reports need to be published in ReportServer
3. ReportName
4. DataSourceName
5. DataSourceFolderName
6. DatabaseName
7. ServerName

These parameter values are given by user with user prompt.

Now I want to call the `rs` utility by passing the `.rss` file (this file has script for publishing the report to reportserver in vb) and the above parameter values are passed from this `.ps1` file.

How can I call `.rss` file with parameters passed in this `.ps1` file?

In batch file I have given as below:

```
rs -i Reports.rss -s %TargetURL% -v TargetFolder="%TargetFolder%" -v SourceReportFolder="%SourceReportFolder%" -v DataSourceFolder="%DataSourceFolder%"  -v DataSourceName="%DataSourceName%" -v ServerName="%ServerName%" -v DataBaseName="%DataBaseName%" -v ReportName="%ReportName%"
```

How can I achieve the same functionality in `.ps1` file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm clear on what you mean. It would also help to see the contents of **TestReports.ps1**. Are you just asking how to translate that batch syntax into PowerShell? This is the PowerShell equivalent of your batch command:

```
rs -i .\Reports.rss -s $TargetURL -v "TargetFolder=`"$TargetFolder`"" -v "SourceReportFolder=`"$SourceReportFolder`" -v "DataSourceFolder=`"$DataSourceFolder`""  -v "DataSourceName=`"$DataSourceName`"" -v "ServerName=`"$ServerName`"" -v "DataBaseName=`"$DataBaseName`"" -v "ReportName=`"$ReportName`""
```

A couple of notes:

- This is assuming that **rs** requires the arguments to **-v** to be in the form `ParameterName="Some Value"`, with the quotation marks passed as part of the string value. If it can take them in the form `ParameterName=Some Value`, you could simplify all the **-v** arguments to `-v TargetFolder=$TargetFolder`, etc, because PowerShell implicitly double-quotes unquoted string arguments.
- A subtle but significant difference between batch and PowerShell: note the `.\` before `Reports.rss`--by default, PowerShell doesn't have the current working directory in the path.

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution, we can use the same code in batch file as is in Powershell script, what we need to do the above command is just replace "% with $ and remove %"

Example:

Script in Batch File:

rs -i TestReports.rss -s %TargetURL% -v TargetFolder="%TargetFolder%" -v SourceReportFolder="%SourceReportFolder%" -v DataSourceFolder="%DataSourceFolder%"  -v DataSourceName="%DataSourceName%" -v ServerName="%ServerName%" -v DataBaseName="%DataBaseName%" -v ReportName="%ReportName%"

Script in Powershell:

rs -i TestReports.rss -s $TargetURL -v TargetFolder=$TargetFolder -v SourceReportFolder=$SourceReportFolder -v DataSourceFolder=$DataSourceFolder  -v DataSourceName=$DataSourceName -v ServerName=$ServerName -v DataBaseName=$DataBaseName -v ReportName=$ReportName

Comment: I'm confused, why did you unaccept and post essentially the same thing as a new answer? If an answer resolves the question, and you want to add some remarks about it that won't fit in a comment, the protocol is to mark the answer as accepted and add your remarks as an update to the question (don't change the substance of the original question, just add this as an update at the bottom).